# Build function that iterates through a dictionary via specific keys mentioned in the function

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

My function contains a global car dictionary, I'm trying to build a function that would sum up three car prices and return it. If you don't find a car then it returns specifically the name of the car mentioned in the function, stating that it doesn't exist.

Here's my dict:

```
CARS = {
  "Honda Accord": 2500,
  "Ford Mustang": 30000,
  "Mercedez Benz C63": 54000,
  "Audi A4": 35000,
  "Toyota Camry": 2300
}
```

And here's how the function should work:

```
def func(car1,car2,car3):
    for k in CARS.keys():
        return CARS[car1] + CARS[car2] + CARS[car3]
    #if k not in CARS.keys():
    #    return f'{k} not found'
```

The last elif is where I'm facing an issue. The first for loop works fine. I want to output that if the user has entered i.e 'Skoda' and it isn't in the dictionary, it should print out `Skoda not found`. Also, is there a neater way of doing this ? TIA

**Edit**
Hey all, okay, so apologies for the weird syntax and logic. I'm basically taking in 3 strings and I want to check whether those strings are in the dictionary, if they are, return the sum of their values else, print out those specific car models that haven't been mentioned in the dictionary and say "car model" not found. That's it.

Comment: Oh also, the input are all in strings.

Comment: Your code won't work like this, the indentation is totally off and the logic doesn't make sense either. First, check whether all keys are in the dictionary and then either print a message or return its value.

Comment: @JanWilamowski forgot to add the indentation.

Comment: That still isn't valid syntax. There's no `elif` to a for loop, only else (and that doesn't make sense here). Also, why are you iterating over all keys if you simply return the values without checking in the first iteration?

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Where does `k` come from?  What does it denote?

Comment: try to rephrase your question from scratch cause logically it doesn't make sense. It's not clear what is the name of the car mentioned in the function

Comment: Hey all, okay, so apologies for the weird syntax and logic. I'm basically taking in 3 strings and I want to check whether those strings are in the dictionary, if they are, return the sum of their values else, print out those specific car models that haven't been mentioned in the dictionary and say "car model" not found. That's it.

Comment: @Aanwar what you explained makes sense. Try to put that in code in exactly that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in Python 3.8.5:

```py
CARS = {
  "Honda Accord": 2500,
  "Ford Mustang": 30000,
  "Mercedez Benz C63": 54000,
  "Audi A4": 35000,
  "Toyota Camry": 2300
}

def func(car1,car2,car3):
    cars_list = [car1,car2,car3]
    try:
        return sum([CARS[i] for i in cars_list])
    except Exception as e:
        return f'{e.args[0]} not found'
print(func('Honda Accord', 'Ford Mustang', 'Audi A4'))
print(func('Honda Accord', 'Ford Mustang', 'Skoda'))
```

Output:

```
67500
'Skoda not found'
```

Comment: So in essence: 
Here's what you did, converted the input into a list, used list comprehension. I just don't understand the e.args[0] bit, is it finding the object that isn't present ?

Comment: Btw, thank you soo much! Would like to let you know that this wasn't an assignment either :) it's just small challenges I'm doing! I guess that's why other people weren't being so nice..

Comment: Hi, `e` here is the Exception content. Since it is a KeyError, the key that is not found in the dict, would be in the `args` attribute of the Exception content `e`, in tuple format. `e.args[0]` returns the key that is not found. So, i simply returned the first index of the `args` attribute of `e` (by using `e.args[0]`) in the f-string. And you're welcome. Thanks for accepting the answer.